# Updating the wordpress Custom table

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am building a dashboard with custom User Data. Each element on the dashboard goes into the loop and shows the related information regarding that user.I am able to show the the custom field using session and loops but i need to update the information as well, somehow it is not updating. Please help with this:

```
<?php 
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'contract';
$wsid = $_SESSION['wedding-values'];
$results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE id=$wsid " );
if ( $results ) {
    foreach ( $results as $result ){
        $wcname=$result->cname;
         $wctname=$result->ctname;
          $waddress=$result->address;
           $wmobile=$result->mobile;
            $wemail=$result->email;
             $wdate=$result->Date;
             $id=$result->id;

    }

}
if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ){

 $wpdb->update($table_name,array(
    'cname'=>$_POST['cname'],array('id'=>$wsid))

       );

}

 ?>
```

Html:

```
<div id="col-md-9">
    <form action="" method="post">
    <table>    
    <tr>
        <td><p style="color: red"> Couple Name </p></td>
        <td><input type=text name=cname placeholder=<?php echo $wcname;?>></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><p style="color: red"> Contact Name </p></td>
        <td><?php echo $wctname;?></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><p style="color: red"> Address </p></td>
        <td><?php echo $waddress;?></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><p style="color: red"> Mobile </p></td>
        <td><?php echo $wmobile;?></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><p style="color: red"> Email</p></td>
        <td><?php echo $wemail;?></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><p style="color: red"> Date Submitted</p></td>
        <td><?php echo $wdate;?></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>

        <td><input type="submit" name="editsave"  value="Edit and Save" ></td>

    </tr>

  </table>
  </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ){

 $wpdb->update($table_name,array(
    'cname'=>$_POST['cname'],array('id'=>$wsid))

       );

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were forget to add this 2 things in query,

`$table_name,array('cname'=>$_POST['cname']),array('id'=>$wsid),array('%s'),array('%d'))`

**array('%s'),array('%d')**

Check this example

```
$result = $wpdb->update($table_name,array(
    'cname'=>$_POST['cname']),array('id'=>$wsid),array('%s'),array('%d'))
);

if($result > 0){
   echo "Successfully Updated";
}
else{
  exit( var_dump( $wpdb->last_query ) );
}
$wpdb->flush();
```

**EDIT**

Also change this

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
```

To

```
if (isset($_POST['editsave']))
```

You were using wrong submit button name

Try with this code. Hope this will helps you.

Comment: I added the code as suggested but it still just gets refreshed and no value is updated or changed.

Comment: Oh yea, my bad! But it still shows me this error: Missing argument 3 for wpdb::update(),

Comment: Thank you . I was missing one closing bracket, it works fine now.

Answer (score -1):

You can output the error

```
if($wpdb->last_error !== '') :
    $wpdb->print_error()
endif;
```

btw, please use $wpdb->prepare to prepares a SQL query for safe execution

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I will add $wpdb->prepare. But it is not displaying any error, the page refreshed but no value goes to the database.